# Catkin - files are not found after install. Wrong directories?

Tags: ros, installation, catkin, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I compiled some packages using catkin. Now on installation ($ catkin_make install) all the files are installed to the catkin_ws/install folder. But there they are not found. I think they should be copied to different systems paths, right?

Do I need to source a file in the workspace to use the compiled and installed files there? How can I get all the files in the right system folders?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59604/catkin---files-are-not-found-after-install.-wrong-directories?/) by [obsti](https://answers.ros.org/users/4515/obsti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-03-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-30**:
Did you configure the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX? Did your CMakeLists.txt invoke the CMake install() macro?

**Comment by [obsti](https://answers.ros.org/users/4515/obsti/) on 2013-03-30**:
No I didn't especially set the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX. To which path do I need to set it? And in the top-level CMakeLists.txt I didn't find any command for the install() macro. How can I set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, the default CMake install location is **/usr/local**, not a good destination for ROS packages. So, you need to [configure your catkin workspace](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace#Configuring_Packages), somewhat like this example:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/build
$ cmake ../src -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install
```

Then, you need to [add CMake **install()** commands](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Optional_Step:_Specifying_Installable_Targets) to your CMakeLists.txt.

For example, if you need to install C++ headers where they can be found by other packages:

```
install(DIRECTORY include/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
)
```

Similarly, if there is a shared libraries needed by other packages at runtime:

```
install(
  TARGETS your_shared_library
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
)
```

Note that catkin library names have system-wide scope, so make sure they clearly describe their role. Include names are less of an issue, since they are usually in a subdirectory under your package name.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [obsti](https://answers.ros.org/users/4515/obsti/) on 2013-03-30**:
What I missed was sourcing the setup.bash in the install directory. Doing this the files are found and the nodes are launching correctly! Thanks a lot joq!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-30**:
That is easy to miss. Glad it's working now.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-06-13**:
Is there a way to embed -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install in CMakeLists.txt so I don't have to remember it on the command line?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-13**:
When you call catkin_make that is always the default location for the install prefix.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-06-13**:
Ah yes, sorry ... that is not exactly what I meant. Is there a way to embed -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/some/place/else in CMakeLists.txt so I don't have to remember it on the command line?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-13**:
You might could do something like this: https://gist.github.com/wjwwood/5779223 (I haven't tried this, might need different syntax or logic)